# Is there a reliable place I can get a local copy of froogaloop2.min.js?

Tags: vimeo, froogaloop

I currently have a site that is using https://secure-a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js but this is sporadic at best. I realize at some point we need to do the migration but is there any cdn server that I can point to for now until we make the transition from froogaloop to the Vimeo api? Does anyone know where I can get a local copy of this?

Answer (score 3):

take it [here](http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js). By the way, if you are using WP - save it to the file and put in your theme.
Remove another version like this in your functions.php:

```
function x_register_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'lbg-vimeo' );   
    wp_register_script('lbg-vimeo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/froogaloop.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'x_register_scripts', 101);
```